# Why the progress function of ng-file-upload was just triggered two times?

Tags: ng-file-upload

I want to use the progress function to show the progress of uploading. However, the progress function was just called two times at the beginning. So the value of progress is always 0.

```html
<input name="file" data-ngf-select type="file" style="display: none" ng-model="uploadCtrl.file"
       ng-show="false" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-change="uploadCtrl.invalidFile()"
       accept="application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
```

```js
Upload.upload(
                {
                    url: PathUtils.qualifiedAPIPath(url),
                    headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    },
                    data: param,
                    method: 'post',
                    arrayKey: ''
                }).then(success, function (error) {
                conn.errorHandler(error.data, error.status)
            }, progress);

function progress() {
            if (document.getElementById("mask") != null) {
                document.getElementById("mask").style.display = 'block';
                $http({
                          'url': PathUtils.qualifiedAPIPath("progress"),
                          'method': "get"
                      }).success(function (res) {
                    document.getElementById("mask-progress").innerHTML = res + '%';
                }).error(conn.errorHandler);
            }
        }
```